Looking for a paper on evaluating integral over Haar ensemble
I remember reading a paper or appendix from the probably the jorunal of high energy physics on the average entropy of a reduced density matrix evolved and averaged over Haar unitary.
The above context could be completely different. The one thing I remember for sure, is they (although it could be a single author paper), evaluated the integral with some clever graphical notation that looks like an attached diagrams. It could be something to do with SU(4) unitary not unitary from Haar distribution...

Does anyone know this paper is?
Sorry for a bad picture, it will be refined in 12 hours.

A good discussion of what you are looking for (how to evaluate such integrals) is in my experience provided in a chapter ("Group integration") of a book by M Creutz on lattice gauge theory, available here.

This isn't a paper that I read, but it surely is helpful for understanding this type of integral evaluation. Thank you!
